# Set up GLFW for OpenGL for C++ without Visual Studio

Tags: c++, glfw

I want to set up GLFW3 to work with C++ in a program called 4coder. I have a folder named libraries that holds all the stuff I need, I just don't know how to get C++ to include them using `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`. I literally started using C++ today and have no idea where to start.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but 4coder is just a text editor, not a IDE. Which compiler are you using? How do you tell the compiler what to do?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add arguments when compiling the source code to specify the location of your headers and libraries. Exactly how this is done will depend on which compiler you are using but for example if you're using g++:

```
path-to-working directory>g++ name-of-file.cpp -Ipath-to-header-files -Lpath-to-library-files -lglfw3 -o name-of-executable
```

The key points here are the -I flag (which tells the compiler where to look for header files) and the -L flag (which tells the compiler where to look for libraries). -lglfw3 will then cause the compiler to look in the directory specified with the -L flag for the glfw3 library.

If you're using a different compiler, the syntax may be different but the general principle will apply - you just have to find the equivalent commands to -I and -L.

Comment: So apparently I figured I have to use Clang. I just need to use one line `clang -c glad.c` to convert some files so I can use them. Problem is, I can't set Clang up.